# Creating large tensors in Tensorflow without crashing the kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to create a video regression model using Tensorflow (predicting heat released from a fire based on the image).

We initially tried a CNN and got good results. We are now trying [Long Term Recurrant Convolutional Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4389).

The problem is that the input from us to the network is `(161,540,960,3)`. 161 frames in a video, (540,960,3) being the size of an image. We further have 193 videos, so the final tensor becomes `(193,161,540,960,3)`

The problem is that I'm trying to create a `tf.Dataset` with this data so it can be batched on input into the network. I am attaching the code I am using to do this **with comments**. The kernel keeps crashing within creating 2 or video files at most.

Is there a more elegant way to create a `tf.Dataset`out of this?

I am running this on Google Colab Pro

```
def create_dataset(df,num_experiments,max_len):
  for i in range(num_experiments):
    for j in range(max_len):
      if j == 0:
        gotten_image = get_img(df.filename_list[i][j]) #Initialize image
        images = gotten_image

        mask = tf.constant([1]) #Initialize mask
        labels = tf.constant([df.hrr_list[i][j]]) #Initialize labels
      else:
        try:
          gotten_image = get_img(df.filename_list[i][j]) #Append image if it exists
          
          mask = tf.concat([mask, tf.constant([1])],0) #Append mask if image exists
          labels = tf.concat([labels, tf.constant([df.hrr_list[i][j]])],0) #Append label if it exists

        except:
          gotten_image = tf.zeros([1,540,960,3]) #Append zeroes if no image exists
          
          mask = tf.concat([mask, tf.constant([0])],0)  #Append zeroes if no image exists
          labels = tf.concat([labels, tf.constant([0.])],0) #Append zeroes if no image exists


        images = tf.concat([images,gotten_image],0) #Layer images from a video one after the other
    
    if i == 0:
      full_images = images
      full_images = tf.expand_dims(full_images,0) #Initialize list of videos

      full_mask = tf.expand_dims(mask,0)
      full_labels = tf.expand_dims(labels,0)
    else:
      images = tf.expand_dims(images,0) 
      full_images = tf.concat([full_images,images],0) #Append one video to the rest

      mask = tf.expand_dims(mask,0)
      labels = tf.expand_dims(labels,0)
      full_mask = tf.concat([full_mask,mask],0) #Append corresponding mask
      full_labels = tf.concat([full_labels,labels],0) #Append coressponding labels


  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((full_images, full_mask), full_labels)) #Create dataset

  return dataset
```

Comment: That:s about 250 gigabytes worth of data. Are you sure your computer can store that much in RAM?

Comment: I’m not sure. I’m trying on my local system now, and it seems like I can create tf.datasets of size (10,161,540,960,3). But I don’t know how else I can process this data either. I’m going to try and see if I can pass each tf.dataset as a batch into the model.